# how to collect more data from a wearOS wearable

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I am creating my first wear OS app in Kotlin. I am trying to collect the different health related data that a wearable measures. I was wondering if there is a way to customise the wearables sensors functions, specifically the data collection frequency.
Let's say my Samsung Galaxy watch has the BioActive Sensor. Is there any possibility with wear OS to trigger this sensor more often and get more measurements from it? I have looked through the documentation but wasn't able to find anything about it. Please help.